# Why my kernel config options did not get enabled at the first make?

Tags: configuration, compilation, linux-kernel, eudyptula-challenge

I was solving Task 02 of Eudyptula Challenge. I had to download latest kernel source, create a working config and change a kernel config flag, boot to newly configured kernel.

I downloaded source and followed below procedure:

1) make localmodconfig -> generated .config from my pc config

2) edited .config and enable required flag -> CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y.

3) make

4) make module

5) make module_install

6) make install

7) update-grub

When I submitted solution I got response that "Linus's tree is newer than this, or you forgot to set the requested configuration option :("
Though my kernel is latest release by Linus. So, i didn't updated or anything.

Then, I decided to build it again and did following:

1) make clean

2) make oldconfig

3) make modules

4) make modules_install

5) make insstall

6) update-grub

And sent logs for review. This time the log passed test.

Here are two dmesg log:

**1)First time log:**

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.16.0-rc3 (sunil@ubuntu) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro         4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #1 SMP Thu Jul 3 00:03:50 PDT 2014
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-rc3 root=UUID=5560b107-9a97-4ca5-8f23-fe1d8798d37b ro quiet splash
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
```

**2) Second time log**

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.16.0-rc3-00149-g034a0f6-dirty (sunil@ubuntu) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #3 SMP Fri Jul 4 18:29:56 IST 2014
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-rc3-00149-g034a0f6-dirty root=UUID=5560b107-9a97-4ca5-8f23-fe1d8798d37b ro quiet splash
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
```

So, why it was not accepted first time?

Comment: what git tree are you cloning ? are you switching to some branch or do you stay on master ?

Comment: Hi @twoface88. No, I neither switch any branch nor tried to update it using git pull. I am using kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git from git.kernel.org.

Answer (score 1):

You have obviously modified something in the source code. Otherwise there would be no 'dirty' string in the version.